# How to convert a type of UIImage(UIAnimatedImage) to NSData to upload with Alamofire

Tags: ios, image, alamofire, gif

I have saved a .gif image in my photo library from google. I can able to show that  .gif image from library to UIImageView, just because when we saved image from browser to our device photo library its saved in the form of NSData format.

I used PHAssets functions to get animated image from NSData. After cropping that UIAnimatedImage, I am unable to save it again in NSData format with its animation.

Can anyone suggest how we can resolved it. So that we can upload that UIAnimatedImage to server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of converting the image back and forth, work with the original `NSData` that you retrieved from your photo library.

Comment: @the4kman, first of all thanks for the reply, but I need to show that NSData as animate image, and after that need to crop that and again show that cropped image as animated image. Can you please let me know how we can do cropping of NSData.